# Cloud Tasks Failing Dispatch with UNKNOWN(2): HTTP status code 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am running Cloud Tasks using OIDC authentication to trigger a Cloud Function. While running ~40K queued tasks, I received a number of task failures (noticed by the fact that the Retries counter was incremented) and when I inspected the Previous Run they all said `Status code 2 (UNKNOWN), Reason to retry UNKNOWN(2): HTTP status code 0`. Additionally, on inspection of the logs, it does not appear that my Cloud Function was triggered. Upon retry of all these tasks, the Cloud Function was triggered and the task was processed successfully.

I am unsure of what this code means and how to respond to it. Are these just par for the course when using Cloud Tasks? Is this definitely not going to trigger my Cloud Function or could it potentially trigger it while also returning this status? Can I protect against this in any way? Am I paying for these failed dispatches?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit the question show the code that doesn't work the way you expect, narrowing it down to the line of code that generates the error.  We can't tell if you might be doing something wrong or how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson none of my code is running here - all of these tasks eventually succeeded with no input from me. This is an internal GCP error on task dispatch, there is no "line of code that generates the error."

Comment: Certainly you must be doing something specific to queue up all these tasks.  How do you suggest that someone reading this question reproduce the issue?

Comment: @DougStevenson maybe my explanation is unclear - the _same exact task_ failed with that error before succeeding - there was no queueing logic (or any lines of user code) executed between failure and success. I am interested in an explanation of the error code, not a code change.

Comment: Hey @AlexWilliams. We've run into the same issue as you. A lot of jobs failing due to HTTP Status Code 0, status UNKNOWN(2) (among other issues with cloud tasks). Did you ever find a solution or did you end up switching your queue driver for something else?

Comment: @Tarps the failed runs don't have any discernible side effects so we accepted it as a known behavior. An idempotence contingency would probably be a good value add but the particular project didn't have the bandwidth for that. We didn't notice the failures being a significant percent of overall volume - are you noticing a high failure rate?